# How can i send javascript variable values into php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

How can i send javascript variable values into php. i have used ajax for this but its nt working for me. please help, i am new in javascript and ajax. Here is my ajax & javascript code.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function ()
    {        
        $("#slider-range").slider(
        {
            range: true,
            min: 71,
            max: 109,
            values: [75, 100],
            slide: function (event, ui)
            {
                $("#size-range").html(Math.floor(ui.values[0] / 12) + "'" + (ui.values[0] % 12) + '" - ' + Math.floor(ui.values[1] / 12) + "'" + (ui.values[1] % 12) + '"');
                $("#min_inches").val(ui.values[0]);
                $("#max_inches").val(ui.values[1]);
            }
        });
        $("#size-range").html(Math.floor($("#slider-range").slider("values", 0) / 12) + "'" + ($("#slider-range").slider("values", 0) % 12) + '" - ' + Math.floor($("#slider-range").slider("values", 1) / 12) + "'" + ($("#slider-range").slider("values", 1) % 12) + '"');
        var a = $("#min_inches").val($("#slider-range").slider("values", 0));
        var b = $("#max_inches").val($("#slider-range").slider("values", 1));

        $.ajax(
        {
            type: "POST",
            url: "searchrange.php",
            data:
            {
                a: a,
                b: b
            },
            success: function (option)
            {
                alert("voted");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

And Below is my php code(searchrange.php).

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['a']) && $_POST['a'] != '')
    {
    $kws = $_POST['a'];
    $kws1=$_POST['b'];
    echo $kws;     
    echo  $query = "select * from newusers where Age between '".$kws."' and '".$kws1."'" ;
    $res = mysql_query($query);
    $count = mysql_num_rows($res);
    $i = 0;
    if($count > 0)
    {
        echo "<ul>";
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
        {
            echo "<a href='#'><li>";     
            echo "<div id='rest'>";?>
            <a href="searchrange.php?id=<?php echo $row['0'];?> "><?php echo $row['Religion'];?><br><?php echo $row['Name'];?></a>
            <?php echo $row[0];
            echo "<br />";
            echo "<br />";    
            echo "<div style='clear:both;'></div></li></a>";
            $i++;
            if($i == 5) break;
        }
        echo "</ul>";
        if($count > 5)
        {
            echo "<div id='view_more'><a href='#'>View more results</a></div>";
        }
    }
    else
    {  
        echo "<div id='no_result'>No result found !</div>";
    }
}
?>
```

Any help would be appreciated. thank you

Comment: Define 'it isn't working'. Do you see an error message? Does anything happen? Is it what you expect, and if not, how does it differ?

Comment: alert "a" variable before sending and see what result you get.

Comment: Your `$.ajax({...})` is being executed on page ready `$(function (){ ... $.ajax({...})  });`. Shouldn't this be executed on a button click / form submit?

Comment: @mahmood rehman: m getting    [object object]   in alert box

Comment: @Sean: when i use $(document).ready.(function(){});

Comment: Are you trying to assign the Min or Maximum variable to "a" and "b" ?

Comment: my slider got disapear

Comment: any issue while if you assign like this var a = min;

Comment: after assigning this when i alert var a i am getting [object object] in alert box

Comment: what this code does ? $("#min_inches").val($("#slider-range").slider("values", 0)); Are you assigning some sort of dynamic value

Comment: yes i am assignig min value of slider to variable a

Comment: @MahmoodRehman: which is dynamic variable

Comment: can you show me some demo or slider link where i can check the code ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass JavaScript variables to PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917576/how-to-pass-javascript-variables-to-php)

Comment: @user3077217 that's nice that your problem solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code :

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery UI Slider - Range slider</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script>
$(function() { 
    $( "#slider-range" ).slider({ 
        range: true, 
        min: 0, 
        max: 500, 
        values: [ 75, 300 ], 
        slide: function( event, ui ) { 
            $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - $" + ui.values[ 1 ] ); 
        },
        change: function(event, ui) {
            // when the user change the slider
        },
        stop: function(event, ui) {
            // when the user stopped changing the slider
               $.ajax(
        {
            type: "POST",
            url: "searchrange.php",
            data:
            {"min" :ui.values[0],"max":ui.values[1]},
            success: function (option)
            {
                alert("voted");
            }
        });
        }
    }); 
    $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) + 
                        " - $" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) ); 
}); 


</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>
<label for="amount">Price range:</label>
<input type="text" id="amount" style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;">
</p>
<div id="slider-range"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And your search page will be like this :

```
 if(isset($_POST['min']) && $_POST['min'] != '')
    {

    $kws = $_POST['min'];
    $kws1=$_POST['max'];
    echo $kws;     
    echo  $query = "select * from newusers where Age between '".$kws."' and '".$kws1."'" ;
    $res = mysql_query($query);
    $count = mysql_num_rows($res);
    $i = 0;
    if($count > 0)
    {
        echo "<ul>";
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
        {
            echo "<a href='#'><li>";     
            echo "<div id='rest'>";?>
            <a href="searchrange.php?id=<?php echo $row['0'];?> "><?php echo $row['Religion'];?><br><?php echo $row['Name'];?></a>
            <?php echo $row[0];
            echo "<br />";
            echo "<br />";    
            echo "<div style='clear:both;'></div></li></a>";
            $i++;
            if($i == 5) break;
        }
        echo "</ul>";
        if($count > 5)
        {
            echo "<div id='view_more'><a href='#'>View more results</a></div>";
        }
    }
    else
    {  
        echo "<div id='no_result'>No result found !</div>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so mch ajax call is  working but the values are not going on php page

Comment: i tested and ajax values are going with min and amx variable to index.php page.Did you replace the index.php with your own page ?

Comment: check now i edit index.php with searchrange.php.you can view the parameters on firebug console.

Comment: rehmaan: have you made any changes to searchrange.php

Comment: @user3077217  No i only work on ajax portion.Your question was parameter are not going with request.what's the issue now ?

Comment: rehmaan: sir i have edited my code to your code but problem is ajax is working(alert(voted) is displaying) but sql query on searchrange.php is still not working

Comment: @user3077217 Replace $_POST['a'] with "min" like  $_POST['min']. It will works.

Comment: @user3077217 check my answer with search.php code.Are you doing like this ?

Comment: sir it is still same.(just boxes are moving ) but not displaying the results

Comment: its because you are alerting the result.add new div with id result and in place of alert write this code.$('#result').html(option);

Answer (score 0):

```
        Try this. Let the ajax call be done inside a call back.

        $(function (){        
             $("#slider-range").slider({
                    range: true,
                    min: 71,
                    max: 109,
                    values: [75, 100],
                    slide: function (event, ui)
                    {
                        $("#size-range").html(Math.floor(ui.values[0] / 12) + "'" + (ui.values[0] % 12) + '" - ' + Math.floor(ui.values[1] / 12) + "'" + (ui.values[1] % 12) + '"');
                        $("#min_inches").val(ui.values[0]);
                        $("#max_inches").val(ui.values[1]);
                        var a = $("#min_inches").val($("#slider-range").slider("values", 0));
                        var b = $("#max_inches").val($("#slider-range").slider("values", 1));

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "searchrange.php",
                    data:
                    {
                        a: a,
                        b: b
                    },
                    success: function (option)
                    {
                        alert("voted");
                    }
                });
              }
           });
$("#size-range").html(Math.floor($("#slider-range").slider("values", 0) / 12) + "'" + ($("#slider-range").slider("values", 0) % 12) + '" - ' + Math.floor($("#slider-range").slider("values", 1) / 12) + "'" + ($("#slider-range").slider("values", 1) % 12) + '"');

     });
```

Comment: my slder box are not moving

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that your `$.ajax({...})` is being called too early - ie. on document ready `$(function (){ ... $.ajax({...}) });`, and not after your sliders are changed/selected. You could call your `$.ajax({...})` on a button click -

```
<input id="vote" type="button" value="Vote" />

$("#vote").on('click',function(){
    var a= $("#min_inches").val();
    var b=$("#max_inches").val();  

    $.ajax ({
            type: "POST",
            url: "searchrange.php",
            data: { a : a,
            b : b },
            success: function(option)
            {
              alert("voted");
            }
            });

});
```

so your code could be -

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function ()
    {        
        $("#slider-range").slider(
        {
            range: true,
            min: 71,
            max: 109,
            values: [75, 100],
            slide: function (event, ui)
            {
                $("#size-range").html(Math.floor(ui.values[0] / 12) + "'" + (ui.values[0] % 12) + '" - ' + Math.floor(ui.values[1] / 12) + "'" + (ui.values[1] % 12) + '"');
                $("#min_inches").val(ui.values[0]);
                $("#max_inches").val(ui.values[1]);
            }
        });
        $("#size-range").html(Math.floor($("#slider-range").slider("values", 0) / 12) + "'" + ($("#slider-range").slider("values", 0) % 12) + '" - ' + Math.floor($("#slider-range").slider("values", 1) / 12) + "'" + ($("#slider-range").slider("values", 1) % 12) + '"');
        $("#min_inches").val($("#slider-range").slider("values", 0));
        $("#max_inches").val($("#slider-range").slider("values", 1));

        $("#vote").on('click',function(){
             var a= $("#min_inches").val();
             var b=$("#max_inches").val();  

             $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "searchrange.php",
                    data:
                    {
                      a: a,
                      b: b
                    },
                   success: function (option)
                   {
                     alert("voted");
                   }
             });
        });
    });
</script>
```

see this JSFiddle example (using alert in place of $.ajax()) -http://jsfiddle.net/8JgW6/

Answer (score 0):

```
    HI,

    You can try this.In this example you can see how I have made a call to ajax

function callService(val1,val2){
            alert("call service here  "+val1);

            $.ajax({
                       type: "POST",
                       url: "searchrange.php",
                       data:
                       {
                           a: val1,
                           b: val2
                       },
                       success: function (option)
                       {
                           alert("voted");
                       }
                   });


   }
  $sliderValue="";
    $(function() {

        $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
          range: true,
          min: 0,
          max: 500,
          values: [ 75, 300 ],
          slide: function( event, ui ) {


          },
          stop: function(event, ui) {            
                    $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - $" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
                    b = 0;
                    $sliderValue=ui.value;
                    console.log($sliderValue)
                    callService($sliderValue,b);
          }
        });
     http://jsfiddle.net/kapilgopinath/c4XA5/
```